# Base64 decode gives different results in Java and Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, base64

I am decoding some text using
    Base64. I have tried three different
    libraries (commons `Base64`, `Java.misc.`, and also java.mail) in Java and all
    of them produce same result for the
    following text, which is not right.

However when I use Ruby to decode the below string I get different output. I get the right result using Ruby.
The Ruby code is `print Base64.decode64('<Below String>')`, the string is

```
RkxWAQEAAAAJAAAAABIAAK4AAAAAAAAAAgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAHAAV3aWR0aABAdAAAAAAA
AAAGaGVpZ2h0AEB0AAAAAAAAAAlmcmFtZXJhdGUAQBAAAAAAAAAADHZpZGVvY29kZWNpZABACAAA
AAAAAAAMY2FuU2Vla1RvRW5kAQEAD21ldGFkYXRhY3JlYXRvcgIAKVNpbXBsZUZMVldyaXRlci5h
cyB2MC44IHplcm9wb2ludG5pbmUuY29tAAAJ
```

The output should start with FLV. I am not sure what I am missing and why the output is different using Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of decoding base64 is *binary* data. You shouldn't really try to print it as if it were text.

Without knowing Ruby, I'd expect the result of calling `Base64.decode64` to be some sort of byte array... and that could be converted into text in any number of ways.

Look at the *bytes* of what's returned to find out whether or not it's correct.

(It's unfortunate that as far as I can see, the [documentation](http://santoro.tk/mirror/ruby-core/classes/Base64.html#M004694) for Base64.decode64 gives examples of exactly the kind of thing you're doing - treating the result of a base64 decode operation as text. It's not clear what type of data is *actually* returned. This sort of thing is why I still like statically typed languages...)

Comment: @Jon - Ruby strings are arbitrary octet sequences

Comment: @McDowell: So when converting those octets to characters in a console, what encoding is used? It sounds like a bad idea to conflate text and binary notions like this...

Comment: Hi Jon, 

    The data that I am trying to convert is a video file which I am sending from client. On the server side, I need to decode the data from Base64 to binary data and write to file. I am getting the output from Base64 decoder as byte array and I am writing this byte array to a file. The problem is the video player is not able to play the video complaining that the file does not start with flv.

Comment: @firemonkey: I suspect it's simply not an ASCII character then, which doesn't surprise me at all. If you take the MD5 sum of both the original file and the one written to disk on the server, do they differ?

Comment: I have printed ascii in both Java and Ruby, All the bytes look same except 17th byte. which is -82 in Java but in Ruby it is 174.

Comment: yes they differ. I have used the diff command on my mac, to compare both the files client vs server. They are different.

Comment: @firemonkey: Java bytes are signed; most other systems are unsigned. 174 and -82 are basically the same value, so that's *not* a difference. You'll need to look elsewhere...

Comment: true but is it possible that video players do not understand that. The reason I am saying that is: If I write the first 198 bytes of the file with the output from Ruby, the video plays fine. I can send both the files to you.

Comment: @firemonkey: No, it's not possible. The file content is the same for that byte. It's just Java's treatment of it which is different. I don't see what you mean by "if I write the first 198 bytes of the file with the output from Ruby". I thought this *was* the output from Ruby.

Comment: @Jon - I agree that printing to the console isn't going to produce any useful output. I was just pointing out that (like C's char type) Ruby conflates the notion of character and byte types, which is probably why `decode64` returns a `String`. _Ruby is unusual in its handling of encoding - rather than define a common encoding, every String has an encoding property. I'm no Ruby expert, but I imagine that could result in some interesting bugs - different ones, at least._

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I totally agree to it. However can you explain why this will not work :

1. Write the out put of above string decoded into bytearray using Java to a file called javaVideo.flv

2. Write the out  put of the above string using ruby to a file called rubyVideo.flv

if you try to play javaVideo.flv, it will complain that the file is not recognizable. however the rubyVideo.flv will open(there is not video content but the file is a valid file content)

I have tried using 3 different video players.

Comment: The code in java I am using to write to file :
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(s);
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(<FILE_PATH>));
   os.write(decodedBytes);

Comment: my bad ... I was using ruby player to play. which probably is causing the problem. It does open up fine when I use Real Player.

thank you very much for all the help

Comment: okay the problem was not writing os.flush() while writing to file. Once I put this statement every thing started working great. thank you again for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to print out into Text? that won't work, try using a ByteArray to store the decoded string.

Example:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

The decoded string actually starts with 'FLV':

```
require 'base64'
Base64.decode64('RkxWAQEAAAAJAAAAABIAAK4AAAAAAAAAAgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAHAAV3aWR0aABAdAAAAAAA AAAGaGVpZ2h0AEB0AAAAAAAAAAlmcmFtZXJhdGUAQBAAAAAAAAAADHZpZGVvY29kZWNpZABACAAA AAAAAAAMY2FuU2Vla1RvRW5kAQEAD21ldGFkYXRhY3JlYXRvcgIAKVNpbXBsZUZMVldyaXRlci5h cyB2MC44IHplcm9wb2ludG5pbmUuY29tAAAJ')
=> "FLV\001\001\000\000\000\t\000\000\000\000\022\000\000\256\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\002\000\nonMetaData\b\000\000\000\a\000\005width\000@t\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\006height\000@t\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\tframerate\000@\020\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\fvideocodecid\000@\b\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\fcanSeekToEnd\001\001\000\017metadatacreator\002\000)SimpleFLVWriter.as v0.8 zeropointnine.com\000\000\t"
```

JRuby 1.6.1