# Decrypt Rails attr_encrypted in Java/Scala

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, scala, encryption

I've taken a look at [trying to decrypt attr_encrypted stored value from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568581/trying-to-decrypt-attr-encrypted-stored-value-from-java) but it didn't provide the help I was looking for (unless I'm misunderstanding...if so please tell me).

I'm using attr_encrypted with the default values, which I believe are, amongst others

```
algorithm: 'aes-256-gcm'
mode: :per_attribute_iv
```

I'm left with the following stored in the DB:

```
encrypted_name: "6t2JNg471ERqz4v3NOcfxI7qzxRhzzfBvwoz",
encrypted_name_iv: "dzPBH0tiYjRs1DJ9"
```

When trying to decrypt these from the JVM

```
val keySpec = new SecretKeySpec('MyKeyHere'.getBytes, "AES")
val spec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * 8, "xI7qzxRhzzfBvwoz".getBytes)
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE")
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, spec)
val sansAuth = encrypted_name.dropRight(16)
cipher.doFinal((encrypted_name_iv + encrypted_name).getBytes)
```

I'm plagued with

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
```

Am I just approaching this entirely incorrectly (I expect I am...)? The last 16 bytes of the encrypted_name should be the tag to use with the GCMParameterSpec yes?

Any help is much appreciated!